# Is there way to add DOM to Forge Viewer without Docking Panel

Tags: autodesk-forge

DockingPanel are prepared in the Forge API UI, but I would like to know if there are APIs that add the DOM created by the user to the Viewer at a more lower layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create an DOM node. It's JavaScript DOM API.

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
viewer.container.appendChild( div );
```